# How to make a textbox wrap text after 21 characters typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input id="textbox" type="text">
```

I'm trying to simulate the textbox that you'd get in a phone's messaging app. After 21 characters are typed, I want to simulate a line break so the text continues under it on a newline instead of just pushing the text passed the edge of the textbox. How do I accomplish this with JS/JQuery?

Comment: Is it really 21 characters? "lllllllllllllllllllll" takes significantly less space than "HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH" in non fixed-width fonts.

Comment: An input won't honor line breaks

Comment: I gave an example input but my actual textbox is longer

Comment: That's the problem. I know how to insert <br> or \n using JS but that doesnt work

Comment: @Andrew If you want people to be able to help you, it's important not to make too many assumptions about what is and isn't important. We have zero context, so it's pretty important to know if it's an `input[type=text]` or a `textarea`

Comment: It's input of type text with a larger width. Where did I say textarea?

Comment: If it is a textarea set the cols to 21 gg <textarea name="Text1" cols="21" rows="5"></textarea>

Comment: I don't see how the `width` of your input is relevant. `input[type=text]` does not honor line breaks as @charlietfl said. Sorry I made an incorrect assumption since you indicated that his comment wasn't applicable.

Comment: @Andrew pretty clear what the element is but showing what you tried is also important and I'm sure while you tried breaking the string you came up with ideas of how you think it should work as well as recognized limitations of `<input>`

Comment: @Scath I tried your code but it didn't work (still scrolled horizontally). Maybe I'm missing something...maybe try a JS Fiddle if you think I'm wrong?

Comment: It doesn't scroll horizontally?? See example in answer

Comment: *facepalm* nvm it works thank you!

Comment: I feel like this is a genuine question, although http://xyproblem.info/ . I don't think this should be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cols` value is based on typing with widest character `W`. You will be able to type a different amount of characters than the `cols` amount in reality. Especially if you allow users to resize the `textarea`.

Instead of using an imprecise HTML attribute like `cols`, you should use CSS and a unit of measurement that is typographical in nature, like **[`em` units](https://www.sitepoint.com/power-em-units-css/)** along with locking down the user's ability to resize the field.

```css
/*
  Assuming we're working with a monospaced font
  Your em value will need to be adjusted depending
  on the font you actually wind up going with.
*/
textarea { width:12em; resize:none; }
```

```html
<textarea name="Text1" rows="5"></textarea>
```